# Google Sheets - How do I grab a value and join it to another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using Google Sheets, I'm working on eCommerce site redirects with 3200 rows of former URLs that need to all have the same new URL, followed by the value (aka, the individual product).

Example of column A (old URLs):
"https://www.example.com/text-text/text/text_text/detail/value/

Example of column B (new URLs):
**/products/**

How do I take **value** from column A and join it after **/products/** in column B?

**Value** changes value for each of the 3200 products.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A1:A),B1:B & REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"[^/]+\/$"),""))
```

to get last word between slashes including last slash

or to exclude last slash use:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A1:A),B1:B & REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,".+\/(.*?)\/$"),""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try like this in row 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A&B1:B)
```